# How to grab div tag value and use it in css file?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a web application where I only have access to edit the css file. I am trying to grab the value (Ex: user23) of this div tag:

```
 <div id="username">user23</div>
```

Then use it in the css file to display the user's image.

```
 div.something {
        content: url(https://website.com/pic?id= /*user name will go here*/ );
 }
```

I have tried methods like attr() to grab the value but instead it grabs "username" instead of the value.

Comment: This **cannot** be done with pure CSS. Are you able to use JavaScript at all? It's possible to construct the relevant CSS values utilising JavaScript, but not with pure CSS.

Comment: agree with @ObsidianAge

Comment: @ObsidianAge I created a javascript file but I cannot add it to html file. How can I call or reference js file from css file?

Comment: ^ You can't reference a JavaScript file from a CSS file. You **must** reference the JavaScript file from the HTML file. That is done with `<script src="FILE_PATH"></script>`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with pure css.
You should use JQuery and do something like that :

```
$("#theDiv").append("<img id='theImg' src='theImg.png'/>");
```